# iOS Chrome and AngularJS does not execute controller in HEAD

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, google-chrome

That happens only in Chrome for iOS.
I have something like that in html.

```
<html ng-app="MY_APP">
<head ng-conroller="headCtrl as head">
<title ng-bind="head.title"></title>
... libraries...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ng-href="./css/{{ head.style }}.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCrtl as main">
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that headCrtl does not executing in Chrome for iOS.

```
MY_APP.controller('headCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', function ($rootScope, $scope, $location) {

    var vm = this;

    var host = $location.host();

    if (host.indexOf('site1') > -1) {
        vm.style = 'site1';
    } else
    if (host.indexOf('site2') > -1) {
        vm.style = 'site2';
    }

    $rootScope.brandCode = vm.style;

    vm.title = 'Straps';


}]);
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Do you know why it wasn't working ? If you have the solution tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your view file. It should be:

```
<head ng-controller="headCtrl as head">
```

not

```
<head ng-conroller="headCtrl as head">
```